# Button after shuffling the options

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I need <kbd>Show Answer 1/2</kbd> to be after the options. But as per my code, it is coming with options.

My Code:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  randomize();
};

function randomize() {
  let questions = $(".question_div");

  questions.each(function() {
    let divCollection = $(this).find(".option_div");
    let divs = Array.from(divCollection);
    shuffleArray(divs);
    for (const div of divs) {
      $(this).append(div);
    }
  });
}

function shuffleArray(array) {
  for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    var temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
  }
}
```

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.option_div {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
}

div.option_div:nth-child(odd) {
  clear: left;
}

.question_div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question_form">

  Question 1
  <div class="question_container">
    <div class="question_div">
      <p>Some persons can do piece of work in 12 days. Twice the number of such persons will do half of that work in, how many days.</p>

      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <input type="hidden" name="qid1" value="244">
      <div class="option_group">
        <div class="option_div">
          <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="checka1" value="A">
          <label for="checka1"><p>1</p>
</label>
        </div>
        <div class="option_div">
          <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="checkb1" value="B">
          <label for="checkb1"><p>2</p>
</label>
        </div>
        <div class="option_div">
          <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="checkc1" value="C">
          <label for="checkc1"><p>3</p>
</label>
        </div>
        <div class="option_div">
          <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="checkd1" value="D">
          <label for="checkd1"><p>4</p>
</label>
        </div>
        <div class="option_div">
          <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="checke1" value="E">
          <label for="checke1"><p>None of these</p>
</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="show_ans" type="button" name="showanswer1" id="showanswer1">Show Answer1</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  Question 2
  <div class="question_container">
    <div class="question_div">
      <p>In a dairy farm, 40 cows eat 40 bags of husk in 40 days. In how many days one cow will eat one bag of husk.</p>
      <input type="hidden" name="qid2" value="245">
      <div class="option_group">
        <div class="option_div">
          <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="checka2" value="A">
          <label for="checka2"><p>&nbsp;44</p>
</label>
        </div>
        <div class="option_div">
          <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="checkb2" value="B">
          <label for="checkb2"><p>45</p>
</label>
        </div>
        <div class="option_div">
          <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="checkc2" value="C">
          <label for="checkc2"><p>48</p>
</label>
        </div>
        <div class="option_div">
          <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="checkd2" value="D">
          <label for="checkd2"><p>40</p>
</label>
        </div>
        <div class="option_div">
          <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="checke2" value="E">
          <label for="checke2"><p>None of these</p>
</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="show_ans" type="button" name="showanswer2" id="showanswer2">Show Answer2</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need <kbd>Show Answer 1/2</kbd> to be after the options. But as per my code, it is coming with options.

Had to repeat the question lines four times as it was not letting to post because of lengthy code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

+1 to the other two answers as they solve your main question query. But after reading your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61838429/button-after-shuffling-the-options#comment109377346_61838740), the below code may help you to get the solution.

I added extra div `question_div2` to get it worked.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  randomize();
  randomizeq();
};

function randomize() {
  let questions = $(".question_div2");

  questions.each(function() {
    let divCollection = $(this).find(".option_div");
    let divs = Array.from(divCollection);
    shuffleArray(divs);
    for (const div of divs) {
      $(this).append(div);
    }
  });
}

function randomizeq() {
  let divCollection = $(".question_div1");
  let divs = Array.from(divCollection);
  shuffleArray(divs);
  $(".question_container").each(function(j) {
    $(this).append(divs[j]);
    $(this).append("<hr><br/>");
  });
}


function shuffleArray(array) {
  for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    var temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
  }
}
```

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.option_div {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
}

div.option_div:nth-child(odd) {
  clear: left;
}

.question_div2 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question_form">

  Question 1
  <div class="question_container">
    <div class="question_div1">
      <div class="question_div2">
        <p>Some persons can do piece of work in 12 days. Twice the number of such persons will do half of that work in, how many days.</p>

        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <input type="hidden" name="qid1" value="244">
        <div class="option_div">
          <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="checka1" value="A">
          <label for="checka1"><p>1</p>
</label>
        </div>
        <div class="option_div">
          <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="checkb1" value="B">
          <label for="checkb1"><p>2</p>
</label>
        </div>
        <div class="option_div">
          <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="checkc1" value="C">
          <label for="checkc1"><p>3</p>
</label></div>
        <div class="option_div">
          <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="checkd1" value="D">
          <label for="checkd1"><p>4</p>
</label>
        </div>
        <div class="option_div">
          <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="checke1" value="E">
          <label for="checke1"><p>None of these</p>
</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br /><button class="show_ans show_answer_button" type="button" name="showanswer1" id="showanswer1">Show Answer1</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  Question 2
  <div class="question_container">
    <div class="question_div1">
      <div class="question_div2">
        <p>In a dairy farm, 40 cows eat 40 bags of husk in 40 days. In how many days one cow will eat one bag of husk.</p>
        <input type="hidden" name="qid2" value="245">
        <div class="option_div">
          <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="checka2" value="A">
          <label for="checka2"><p>&nbsp;44</p>
</label>
        </div>
        <div class="option_div">
          <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="checkb2" value="B">
          <label for="checkb2"><p>45</p>
</label>
        </div>
        <div class="option_div">
          <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="checkc2" value="C">
          <label for="checkc2"><p>48</p>
</label>
        </div>
        <div class="option_div">
          <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="checkd2" value="D">
          <label for="checkd2"><p>40</p>
</label></div>
        <div class="option_div">
          <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="checke2" value="E">
          <label for="checke2"><p>None of these</p>
</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br /><button class="show_ans show_answer_button" type="button" name="showanswer2" id="showanswer2">Show Answer2</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just moved the button to a level above and it worked. I hope it's that what you wanted.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  randomize();
};

function randomize() {
  let questions = $(".question_div");

  questions.each(function() {
    let divCollection = $(this).find(".option_div");
    let divs = Array.from(divCollection);
    shuffleArray(divs);
    for (const div of divs) {
      $(this).append(div);
    }
  });
}

function shuffleArray(array) {
  for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    var temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
  }
}
```

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.option_div {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
}

div.option_div:nth-child(odd) {
  clear: left;
}

.question_div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question_form">

  Question 1
  <div class="question_container">
    <div class="question_div">
      <p>Some persons can do piece of work in 12 days. Twice the number of such persons will do half of that work in, how many days.</p>

      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <input type="hidden" name="qid1" value="244">
      <div class="option_group">
        <div class="option_div">
          <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="checka1" value="A">
          <label for="checka1"><p>1</p>
</label>
        </div>
        <div class="option_div">
          <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="checkb1" value="B">
          <label for="checkb1"><p>2</p>
</label>
        </div>
        <div class="option_div">
          <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="checkc1" value="C">
          <label for="checkc1"><p>3</p>
</label>
        </div>
        <div class="option_div">
          <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="checkd1" value="D">
          <label for="checkd1"><p>4</p>
</label>
        </div>
        <div class="option_div">
          <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="checke1" value="E">
          <label for="checke1"><p>None of these</p>
</label>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <button class="show_ans" type="button" name="showanswer1" id="showanswer1">Show Answer1</button>
  </div>

  Question 2
  <div class="question_container">
    <div class="question_div">
      <p>In a dairy farm, 40 cows eat 40 bags of husk in 40 days. In how many days one cow will eat one bag of husk.</p>
      <input type="hidden" name="qid2" value="245">
      <div class="option_group">
        <div class="option_div">
          <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="checka2" value="A">
          <label for="checka2"><p>&nbsp;44</p>
</label>
        </div>
        <div class="option_div">
          <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="checkb2" value="B">
          <label for="checkb2"><p>45</p>
</label>
        </div>
        <div class="option_div">
          <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="checkc2" value="C">
          <label for="checkc2"><p>48</p>
</label>
        </div>
        <div class="option_div">
          <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="checkd2" value="D">
          <label for="checkd2"><p>40</p>
</label>
        </div>
        <div class="option_div">
          <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="checke2" value="E">
          <label for="checke2"><p>None of these</p>
</label>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <button class="show_ans" type="button" name="showanswer2" id="showanswer2">Show Answer2</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried that before coming here, but the issue was not solved. As I am also shuffling questions. https://jsfiddle.net/1wpjngq2/

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are facing caused by appending `options` to the question tag using javascript, [`.append()`](https://api.jquery.com/append/) will add HTML after what currently inside the element you are appending to, its not an CSS/HTML issue, just move the button to the parent of `question_div` (after the closing tag of `question_div`),

update: to fix the issue you are facing I updated `randomizeq()` function to grab the button and append it just before the `<hr>` tag:

```
function randomizeq() {
   let divCollection = $(".question_div");
  let divs = Array.from(divCollection);
  shuffleArray(divs);
  $(".question_container").each(function(j) {
    $(this).append(divs[j]);
    $(this).append($(`#showanswer${j+1}`));
    $(this).append("<hr><br/>");
  });
}
```

Working snippet and [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mamounothman/47q5g8se/13/) too:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  randomize();
 randomizeq();
};

function randomize() {
  let questions = $(".question_div");

  questions.each(function() {
    let divCollection = $(this).find(".option_div");
    let divs = Array.from(divCollection);
    shuffleArray(divs);
    for (const div of divs) {
      $(this).append(div);
    }
  });
}

function randomizeq() {
   let divCollection = $(".question_div");
  let divs = Array.from(divCollection);
  shuffleArray(divs);
  $(".question_container").each(function(j) {
    $(this).append(divs[j]);
    $(this).append($(`#showanswer${j+1}`));
 $(this).append("<hr><br/>");
  });
}

function shuffleArray(array) {
  for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    var temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
  }
}
```

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.option_div {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
}

div.option_div:nth-child(odd) {
  clear: left;
}
.question_div {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question_form">

  Question 1
  <div class="question_container">
    <div class="question_div">
      <p>Some persons can do piece of work in 12 days. Twice the number of such persons will do half of that work in, how many days.</p>

      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <input type="hidden" name="qid1" value="244">
      <div class="option_group">
        <div class="option_div">
          <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="checka1" value="A">
          <label for="checka1"><p>1</p>
</label>
        </div>
        <div class="option_div">
          <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="checkb1" value="B">
          <label for="checkb1"><p>2</p>
</label>
        </div>
        <div class="option_div">
          <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="checkc1" value="C">
          <label for="checkc1"><p>3</p>
</label>
        </div>
        <div class="option_div">
          <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="checkd1" value="D">
          <label for="checkd1"><p>4</p>
</label>
        </div>
        <div class="option_div">
          <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="checke1" value="E">
          <label for="checke1"><p>None of these</p>
</label>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <button class="show_ans" type="button" name="showanswer1" id="showanswer1">Show Answer1</button>
  </div>

  Question 2
  <div class="question_container">
    <div class="question_div">
      <p>In a dairy farm, 40 cows eat 40 bags of husk in 40 days. In how many days one cow will eat one bag of husk.</p>
      <input type="hidden" name="qid2" value="245">
      <div class="option_group">
        <div class="option_div">
          <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="checka2" value="A">
          <label for="checka2"><p>&nbsp;44</p>
</label>
        </div>
        <div class="option_div">
          <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="checkb2" value="B">
          <label for="checkb2"><p>45</p>
</label>
        </div>
        <div class="option_div">
          <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="checkc2" value="C">
          <label for="checkc2"><p>48</p>
</label>
        </div>
        <div class="option_div">
          <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="checkd2" value="D">
          <label for="checkd2"><p>40</p>
</label>
        </div>
        <div class="option_div">
          <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="checke2" value="E">
          <label for="checke2"><p>None of these</p>
</label>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <button class="show_ans" type="button" name="showanswer2" id="showanswer2">Show Answer2</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried that before coming here, but the issue was not solved. As I am also shuffling questions. https://jsfiddle.net/1wpjngq2/

Comment: Appreciated, the query was solved immediately but the button should also get shuffled with their questions. Like:- Some persons can do...... should have `<button class="show_ans" type="button" name="showanswer1" id="showanswer1">Show Answer1</button>` only then it will show correct answer for requested.